# JVM and programmatic exceptions

Tags: java

Can I say `JVM exceptions` are unchecked exceptions and `Programmatic exceptions` are checked exceptions? Because it seems like JVM exceptions are thrown at runtime so could not be checked...

Thanks

Comment: All exceptions are thrown at runtime. What are JVM exceptions? I don't think that's a standard term.

Comment: No, you can't say that. Any program can choose to throw both kinds of exceptions (checked and runtime). Read the [tutorial on exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). I don't know what you mean by *programmatic* and *JVM* exceptions.

Comment: Oh, I am confused. I get the term `JVM exception` from K&B's SCJP6 study guide. It says `RuntimeException` extends `Exception` hence it is not a checked exception. Some of Exception subclasses can be thrown by JVM, like ClassCastException, but NumberFormatException is typically thrown programmaticlly.

Comment: That's an odd concept to define. All exceptions are thrown programmatically. It is true that some are seldom thrown by code not in the standard library, like ClassCastException or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but nothing stops you from using them in your code.

Comment: If it really says "RuntimeException extends Exception hence it is not a checked exception", then it's saying nonsense.

Comment: @JB Nizet My bad. I tried to modify the comments but SO doesn't allow me. I wanted to say RuntimeException extends Exception `BUT` it is not a checked exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be two separate distinctions involved in what you are asking. Exception thrown by the JVM runtime extend from `Error` whereas programmatic exceptions extend from `Exception`. Unchecked programmatic exceptions extend from `RuntimeException`. So there are two distinct class hierarchies for unchecked exceptions. Do note that the JVM/programmatic distinction is convention only: you can indeed throw any exception class you want from Java code.

Also make sure to distinguish JVM exceptions from JDK exceptions—those thrown by the standard Java library. No JVM exception is checked, but a lot of JDK exceptions are.

As for the checked/unchecked distinction, the compiler forces you to declare in advance all checked exceptions your method may throw either explicitly or by calling a method that may throw them. No such checking is done for unchecked exceptions.

Comment: The JVM also throws exceptions that extend from RuntimeException, not only errors. For example, `ArithmeticException` when you divide by zero, `NullPointerException` when you try to de-reference `null`, and `ClassCastException` when you try to do an illegal cast.

Comment: @Joni A good point, but note that these could be argued to be thrown by Java-the-language and not by the JVM implementation: the situations in which they are thrown are precisely dictated by the JLS and the cause always lies with errors in client code (this distinguishes them from Errors).

Answer (score 1):

By JVM exception you probably think about exceptions thrown by the Java VM, while Programmatic exceptions are exceptions that are thrown by the java programmers code.

Most exceptions thrown by the Java VM is actually thrown by java code in the standard libraries in the Java VM. You can download this java code and you will see that the libraries throws exceptions in the same way as a programmer that writes a java program. A standard java programmer can also throw the same exceptions in the same way.

The Java VM may also throw Java Errors. An Error is not an Exception, but can be thrown and catched in the same way as Exceptions. Only the VM should throw an Error.

Comment: Thanks. So sounds like all exceptions are kind of Programmatic-wise exceptions and according to Joni's comments all of them are throw at run-time, but they may not to be subclass of RuntimeException.

Comment: Also Can I ask about is there a mapping between JVM exception/Programmtic exception and checked/unchecked exception?

Comment: The terminology here is a bit off. Anything thrown is an exception, that's how the term is defined by the specification. It is another thing that the class names do't quite follow this. It could be due to a late design decision to introduce a separate hierarchy for Errors, entailing a new base class for exceptions, Throwable.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Thank you Marko, I am still a little confused about the term `checked/unchecked` exceptions. Seems to me the difference is whether programmer need/not to check that exception within the code. But that term has nothing relative to JVM. Is that right? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can I say JVM exceptions are unchecked exceptions and Programmatic exceptions are checked exceptions?

First, "JVM exceptions" is not standard terminology.  (And the fact SCJP6 talks about exceptions that are thrown by the JVM doesn't make your terminology correct.  The SCJP6 text that you quoted is using the words descriptively ... not as an attempt to define terminology.)

The answer to your question is No.  Many "programmatic" exceptions are unchecked.  For instance, `NumberFormatException` is unchecked.

> Because it seems like JVM exceptions are thrown at runtime so could not be checked...

That logic doesn't make sense either.  All exceptions are thrown at runtime.  This is not what "checked" versus "unchecked" means.  The real distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions is that checked exceptions must be either caught or declared in the method signature.  With unchecked exceptions you don't have to do either.

Now it so happens that all exceptions that are thrown by the JVM itself ARE unchecked.  But that is more about the nature of the "events" that trigger the exceptions.  They are typically the result of either a bug in some Java code, or a non-recoverable JVM failure.  These are not the kind of thing that an application typically recovers from, so it making them unchecked simply avoids some unnecessary verbiage (or worse) in the source code.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Very helpful insight. :)